# How do I get all the data from an array and store it in a new variable or constant?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, while-loop

So I am trying to use the data in my array to add it to a variable. The variable name is `newValue`. I have an array called `numbers` and this is what it looks like

`let numbers = [2,8,1,16,4,3,9]`

I have another var that is sum 'var sum = 0'. And finally another one called counter `var counter = 0`

So! Here is all of my code.

```
let numbers = [2,8,1,16,4,3,9]
var sum = 0
var counter = 0

while counter < numbers.count {
    var newValue = numbers
    sum = sum + newValue
    counter++
}
```

as you can se I'm trying to add the values to my var newValue. How?

I am so sorry that the code looks like that but it just does not work when I try to make a multi line code block. If anybody know then tell me. Other wise you could place the code in a text editor of some sort idk. Thank all of you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error is because you are adding `Int` to `[Int]`, i.e. an Int to `Array <Int>`(You can only add property of same `Type`), what you need to do is add Int to and element of `Array<Int>` by accessing the `element` by `counter` as `Index` value.

> Using the value of **counter as an index value**, **retrieve** each **value** from
>   the array and add

```
let numbers = [2,8,1,16,4,3,9]
var sum = 0
var counter = 0

while counter < numbers.count {
    var newValue = numbers
    sum = sum + newValue[counter] // use counter to access element of Array
    counter += 1 // also ++ is deprecated // now use += 1 instead 
}

print(sum) // 43
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I get it now and will look through the logic once again!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the sum of array you can try this...

```
let numbers = [2,8,1,16,4,3,9]
var sum = 0
for each in numbers {
    sum = sum + each
}
print(sum)  //Prints -->> 43
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not what I am looking for. I am currently learning swift and I have a code challenge on teamtreehouse.com.  The challenge states: Now that we have the while loop set up, it's time to compute the sum!
Using the value of counter as an index value, retrieve each value from the array and add it to the value of sum.

For example: sum = sum + newValue. Or you could use the compound addition operator sum += newValue where newValue is the value retrieved from the array.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you add the type to your variables.

1. Notice that you initialize `numbers` as an array of `Integers`, and
   sum is an `Integer`. These two can't be added to each other.

   Instead  of `var sum = 0` use `var sum: Int = 0`
2. You are using a `while` loop and could use a `for-in` or `for-each` loops
3. When looping you are declaring `var NewValue = numbers`, maybe consider to decleare `var newValue = 0` only once outside the loop
4. Back to your question, if you still want to use the `while` loop, and **minimum changes**. Notice the comments

   ```
   let numbers = [2,8,1,16,4,3,9]
   var sum = 0
   var counter = 0

   while counter < numbers.count {
      // var newValue = numbers //new value is now array and that's not what you want
      var newValue = numbers[counter] // I think that is the change you are looking fot 
      sum = sum + newValue
      counter += 1  // ++ is deprecated in swift
   }
   ```